# Мобильное меню сайта

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Ситуация следующая - на сайте [maryno.solisun.ru](http://maryno.solisun.ru) в мобильной версии сайта есть проблема:

Если находишься на главной странице сайта, то при нажатии на бургер видишь уже раскрытые dropdown меню, на других страницах сайта такой проблемы нет.

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83/5264#5264)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На главной странице у списков подменю изначально проставлено

```
<ul style="display: block;">
```

а должно быть

```
<ul style="display: none;">
```

как на других страницах. Смотрите, где формируется код меню

Comment: правда, но где может скрываться проблема, если это хедер и стиль к нему одинаков для всех страниц?

Comment: Стиль css. Одинаков. Но в данном случае стиль внесен прямо в html. Надо смотреть где формируется html-код меню.

Comment: Проблема может быть в скрипте?

Comment: Может быть где угодно